# Will installing as dual-boot harm my factory restore partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I have a new Toshiba Satellite P740 laptop running the 64-bit version of Windows 7 Home Premium. At the moment, the machine comes with a secret partition that will restore the computer to its out-of-the-box, factory-fresh state by using a key combination at startup.

If I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on this machine, will I still be able to access the secret partition? I'd like to be able to restore the machine this way if I ever need to sell it or something else goes horribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not do any harm to your factory partition and yes, You can restore from this secret partition unless and until you delete that partition in the Installation phase of Ubuntu.

Please, take **special care** for not to delete that partition by Gparted or "Partition Disk" phase of Ubuntu installation.

I had a partition in My Lenovo 3000 Y410, I installed Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora and many others and Windows XP and 7. It did not delete the partition. Yes, If you deliberately delete that partition *(as I did)*, It will get deleted.

#### How to identify the secret partition:

Most of the time, The secret partition resides as the *First* or *last* partition of the disk. As @izx suggested, You can see that partition in Windows by *Clicking* on Start button, then type `diskmgmt.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then select the *Disk management* in the left bar. Windows does not assign a Drive letter such as `C:` or `D:` to this partition. Most probably, Windows can show this partition as **Hidden partition** or something similar.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Will the recovery partition be clearly labeled as such? I don't want to delete it by mistake.  (Please forgive my ignorance; I'm a complete noobie and don't want to make a mistake I can't fix.)

Comment: @Beth, in Windows, can you press the Start globe, and type "diskmgmt.msc", then Enter, you will get the disk map. Can you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: @Beth, I have added something more in my answer. And as izx suggested, if you can take a screenshot of the "disk management" window and include in your answer, We can say what that recovery partition is. Yes, I appreciate your carefulness. This is necessary, Since you can't have that partition after deleting

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!The screenshot won't be necessary (and I'm not logged in on my Windows machine right now anyway; I'm using my husband's Linux one).  The recovery partition is clearly labeled as such.  There's also a partition labeled TI106332W0C (C:), which is the NTFS one, and another primary partition.

Comment: @Beth, You can consider selecting the answer, Which can help future visitor, Thanks that, you have identified

Answer (score 6):

Nothing *should* happen to that partition as long as you are dual-booting, i.e. installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. Ubuntu will simply reduce the size of your main Windows partition and squeeze itself in.

Before:

```
  [100MB Winboot |            100 GB C:\                | 15 GB Restore Partition]
```

After:

```
  [100MB Winboot |  70 GB C:\   |   30 GB Ext4-Ubuntu   | 15 GB Restore Partition]
```